# Unable to on/off mobile data on android device 4.1.2

Tags: android

I use the code below to on/off mobile data and its works fine on the android devices having 2.3 and above.i also tested it on the android devices having os 4.2.1 and it works fine. but throws exception (java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: mService)on the device having os 4.1.2.

```
public boolean repairDataConnection(boolean ON, Context context) 
{
    Log.d(tag,"Repair Data Connection work");
    int bv = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    try 
    {
        if (bv == Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
        {
            Method dataConnSwitchmethod;
            Class<?> telephonyManagerClass;
            Object ITelephonyStub;
            Class<?> ITelephonyClass;

            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            telephonyManagerClass = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
            Method getITelephonyMethod = telephonyManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");
            getITelephonyMethod.setAccessible(true);
            ITelephonyStub = getITelephonyMethod.invoke(telephonyManager);
            ITelephonyClass = Class.forName(ITelephonyStub.getClass().getName());

            if (ON) 
            {
                dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod("enableDataConnectivity");
            } 
            else 
            {
                dataConnSwitchmethod = ITelephonyClass.getDeclaredMethod("disableDataConnectivity");
            }
            dataConnSwitchmethod.setAccessible(true);
            dataConnSwitchmethod.invoke(ITelephonyStub);
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Log.e(">>>>","App running on Ginger bread+");
            final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            final Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
            final Field iConnectivityManagerField = conmanClass.getDeclaredField("mService");
            iConnectivityManagerField.setAccessible(true);
            final Object iConnectivityManager = iConnectivityManagerField.get(conman);
            final Class<?> iConnectivityManagerClass = Class.forName(iConnectivityManager.getClass().getName());
            final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = iConnectivityManagerClass.getDeclaredMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
            setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(iConnectivityManager, ON);
        }
        return true;
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        try {
            Log.d(tag,"Exception...."+e);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            Log.d(tag,"Exception...."+e1);
        }

    }
    return false;

}
```

Comment: Any alternate to do this.

Comment: Facing the same problem.. Did you get any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem today.
Solved this way:

```
final ConnectivityManager conman = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
final Class<?> conmanClass = Class.forName(conman.getClass().getName());
final Method setMobileDataEnabledMethod = conmanClass.getMethod("setMobileDataEnabled", Boolean.TYPE);
setMobileDataEnabledMethod.setAccessible(true);
setMobileDataEnabledMethod.invoke(conman, Boolean.valueOf(ON));
```